# FileNotFoundException on saveAsNewHadoopFile

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm performing bulk loading of data into HBase using Spark. My Python script works perfectly to do this job, however I need to be able to submit this using spark submit so that I can run it on the cluster.

When I run the script locally with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/bin/spark-submit\
  --master local[*]\
  --deploy-mode client\
  --verbose\
  --num-executors 3\
  --executor-cores 1\
  --executor-memory 512m\
  --driver-memory 512m\
  --conf\
    spark.logConf=true\
  /test/BulkLoader.py
```

it works perfectly - loads the data, writes the HFiles, bulk loads them. However, when I run the code with YARN as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/bin/spark-submit\
  --master yarn\
  --deploy-mode client\
  --verbose\
  --num-executors 3\
  --executor-cores 1\
  --executor-memory 512m\
  --driver-memory 512m\
  --conf\
    spark.logConf=true\
  --conf\
    spark.speculation=false\
  /test/BulkLoader.py
```

things go wrong quickly. As soon as the script tries to write the HFile, I get the following error:

```
 An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 26 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.25 in stage 15.0 (TID 67, sandbox.hortonworks.com): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hfiles-06-46-57/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201602150647_0019_r_000000_25/f1 does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
...
```

When writing the HFile, a FileNotFoundException is raised on a `_temporary` directory. I looked around and found that many other people had encountered such errors ([here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201509.mbox/%3CJIRA.12733399.1407823694000.340351.1442307345812@Atlassian.JIRA%3E) and [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=issues@spark.apache.org&q=subject:%22%5Bjira%5D+%5BCommented%5D+(SPARK-2984)+FileNotFoundException+on+_temporary+directory%22&o=newest&f=1)) however nothing suggested worked for me. I set the number of executors to 1 and set speculation to false since this was suggested as the likely cause of the error, however the problem persists. If anybody could suggest other options for me to explore, I'd be grateful.

Comment: First I would check if the file is there, so you know if the problem is that the file was not created, or it can't be found. Mostly it is the first one, if that's the case, there might be some warnings previously that it couldn't be created, maybe due to permissions.

Comment: @DanielZolnai That was my first guess. However this is a temporary directory created during HFile creation. Typically, the partial files are written into a temp directory, then afterwards copied back out and the temp directory is deleted. It seems more like a parallelisation issue, but I have no real control over how Spark parallelises the tasks.

Comment: If it is not very much data, you could `rdd.coalesce(1)` with your data, which will collect it in one partition on one machine. If you write it afterwards, then there should not be parallellisation issues, since it is only on one machine (which is not efficient, but helps you filter issues).

Comment: @DanielZolnai Hmmm. I'll try that and report. Thanks.

Comment: Try this setting ("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false");

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem was that I was writing the files to the local file system instead of HDFS - when running in the cluster, Spark demands HDFS since it is a shared file system.